# How to achieve menu effect on samsung in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I recorded a video of the effect here:

https://www.youtube.com/shorts/DppXTO747oI

as far as i can see it will use page view or sliding up panel with vertical direction, right?, i'm not sure,

it has too much knowledge i need to learn, animation ?, fade in fade out, trans Y, X...,
Can someone explain to me in detail what to do to achieve the effect like the video above, thanks